# How $this->authorize() understand which policy should be called in laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, policy

I have a few policies like
`CoursePolicy`,
`PostPolicy`,
`CommentPolicy` is defined in Laravel policy folder.

As well as I registered all the policies under the policy array in the boot method of `AuthServiceProviderClass`.

But how does Laravel knows which policy class's method(in this case view method) should be called when writing in controller class!?

```
$this->authorize( 'view', Course::findOrFail( $course ) );
```

Comment: It tries to look for `CoursePolicy` in `App\Policies` (if I am not mistaken on the path) and if it is found, it will look for `view` method. When in doubt, always check the source code: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/025c9128994eefd3351061a971c0bbc909680b37/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.php#L19-L24. At the end, you will come to here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/025c9128994eefd3351061a971c0bbc909680b37/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L392-L405, see the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#creating-policies), for each `model` you do a corresponding `policy` to authorize user actions (these actions are related to viewing, creating, updating, and deleting the resource).

When registering policies you inform Laravel which `policy` to use when authorizing actions against a given `model` type.

If you used the `--model` option (ex: `php artisan make:policy CoursePolicy --model=Course`) when generating your policy via the Artisan console, it will already contain methods for the `viewAny`, `view`, `create`, `update`, `delete`, `restore`, and `forceDelete` actions.

You are using the [Controller Helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers) `$this->authorize()`, so you need to  write the name of the action on the correct method, and will return a exception with 403 if it fails.

This is the map for controller method<->policy method so you don't name other policy on different method.

| Controller Method | Policy Method |
| --- | --- |
| index | viewAny |
| show | view |
| store | create |
| create | create |
| edit | update |
| update | update |
| destroy | delete |

Answer (score 0):

Laravel determines the policy based on the model you send to it. According to the official Laravel documentation, some policy methods like `create` do not require a model instance. You should pass a class name using the `authorize` method in these situations. This class name will be used to determine which policy to use when authorizing the action:

```
$this->authorize( 'create', Course::class );//this will check create method in Course Model
$this->authorize( 'create', Post::class );//this will check create method in Post Model 
$this->authorize( 'create', Comment::class );//this will check create method in Comment Model
```